# chain routes in a route handler in NodeJs / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

when dealing with routes, I want to check if the route is valid. If not, I always want to redirect to a `notFound` page.

If the user is not authorized I always want to redirect to the `login` page.

Otherwise I want to use the valid routes.

In my `app.js` I require my `router.js` and pass in the app as a parameter

```
require('./server/router')(app);
```

So my router works fine when having

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.use('/route1', require('./routes/route1'));
    app.use('/route2', require('./routes/route2'));
    app.use('/route3', require('./routes/route3'));
};
```

in there. When using this structure

```
module.exports = function(){
    var router = require('express').Router();
    router.use('/route1', require('./routes/route1'));
};
```

it results in

`Cannot GET /route1`

All my routes contain this base structure

```
var router = require('express').Router();

// -- Route --

router.get('/', function (req, res) { // Render the HTML here
        res.render('route1', {
        });
});

// -- Ajax POST --

router.post('/doSomething', function (req, res) { // Load some data
    res.send({});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Is it not possible to use the router when it comes to require the routes?

Further I want to implement the check for invalid routes or authorized users.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.route){
    res.redirect('/notFound'); // invalid route
  } else {
    var session = req.session;
    if (session.user == null){ // unauthorized user
      res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
      // valid routes here
    }
  }
});
```

How can I connect this pseudo code with my valid routes?

Comment: Are you using a general error handler for your app?

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: `express` throws errors automatically if something is wrong. Usually you put an error handler in `app.js` to generate error messages and status. However, `404` errors are a different case and will need to be handled separately. I can give you an example if you want.

Comment: that would be nice, yeah :)

Comment: @YouneL's answer should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put at the end of your express app.js

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);

});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if(err.status == 404)   res.redirect('/notFound')
// can  handle more conditions (like 500) also  
})
```

Comment: I added this snippet at the end of my `app.js` and at the end of my `router.js`, both ways did not work

Comment: make sure if you already used  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {  middleware then append condition to that. also check and post res.status value for route that not exists

Comment: sorry it should be 404 check again

Comment: when using the updated code the server freezes. I tested both ways, it instantly freezes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162826/discussion-between-shivshankar-and-peterhasemann).

Comment: The error is here `if(res.status == 404)` , it should be `if(err.status == 404)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a middleware for checking authorized users on top of all routes, and another to handle not found routes at the end:

handle unauthorized users:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    next();
});
```

catch not found routes:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send('Page Not Found');
});
```

You may want to render error view by using `res.render('error', {code: 404, msg: 'Page Not Found'});`

Comment: using `res.render('error', {code: 404, msg: 'Page Not Found'});` is excellent!